# IDA SDK Loader: memory mapping

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I'm trying to write a loader for a file type I have. It's basically a binary file that has a bunch of bootloader ROM data in it(multiple bootloaders). I can parse the file and load all the BLs into the database just fine. My problem is that each bootloader sometimes loads data from inside its address range. So for example, if I load the 3rd bootloader into the database and then examine its code I might see it try to access some data at 0x10 into its own range. When I hover over that 0x10 and or double click it I am taken to 0x10 at the start of the database and not the start of that specific bootloader. Is there any way I can get it to show me what is at 0x10 in its own memory range?

I have each BL in its own code segment. 
So I'd basically like each BL segment to act like its own database.

To help explain it better, lets say I have BL1 from 0 - 0x1000, BL2 from 0x1000 - 0x2000 and BL3 from 0x2000 - 0x3000 in the database.